# How to change EOL coding in txt files?

Tags: c++, file, eol

I am writing in Visual Studio 2008 in C++ and I have problems with other libraries - they do not accept the line endings (EOL) I generate with my txt files.

How can I change that while writing a file with

```
std::ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("traindata.txt");
myFile << "stuff" << endl;
// or 
//myFile << "stuff" << '\n';
myFile.close();
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Ok, I did a mistake in code : I was appending "0 " for every iteration so that I had whitespace before the EOL.

By bad. You guys have been right. Thanks for help.

Comment: Which line endings is your code generating? Which line endings do these "other libraries" expect?

Comment: @GregHewgill I am not really sure which one is being generated but I need LF.

Comment: When you use `endl` or `\n` on windows, it gets automatically converted to CRLF when in text mode.

Comment: I recommend you become familiar with a hex editor so you can (a) find out what you're generating now, and (b) ensure that you've done the right thing when you change your code.

Comment: @Jesse So what can I do to get LF ? I have tried with `myFile.open("traindata.txt", std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::binary);` and no success :(

Comment: I have tried '\n' and the file's EOLs look exactly like the desired one but still I have some problems ;/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you just don't want the \n to end of line sequence to happen? Open your file using `std::ios_base::binary`: this turns off precisely the conversion. ... and don't use `std::endl` unless you really want to flush the stream:

```
std::ofstream myFile("traindata.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
myFile << "stuff\n";
```

The `close()` is typically also unnecessary unless you want to check that it was successful.

Comment: I somehow seemed to remember that std::endl would not flush the buffer when applied to a text file, but I can only find things that confirms 100% what you are stating here.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the file stream in binary mode to keep C++ library from converting line endings automatically:

```
myFile.open("traindata.txt", std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::binary);
```

That will keep C++ library from converting '\n' to OS-specific EOL symbol (CR-LF on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Download notepad++ - that should be able to fix the problem.

Or `dos2unix`, `unix2dos` on `cygwin`

Answer (score -1):

Use `myfile << "\r\n"` for the Windows-style ending, or `myfile << "\n"` for the UNIX-style.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer because on Windows, writing `"\n"` to a text file is silently converted to `"\r\n"`.

Comment: -1. Using `myfile << "\n"` will still produce CRLF line endings on Windows because the file is opened in text mode.  The substitution is performed in the low level file services.

Comment: @GregHewgill What about `\n` ?